# set attribute when attribute changes in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a class which has an attribute that is a pandas dataframe. I would like to define another attribute in the same class that changes when the dataframe is altered. I thought that a setter might be the correct approach but I haven't been able to get it to work. Here is a toy example:

```
import pandas as pd

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, df=None):
        self._df = df
        self.altered = False # bool, set to True if self._df changes
    @property
    def df(self):
        return self._df
    @df.setter
    def df(self, df):
        self.altered = True # since _df might change here set self.altered True
        self._df = df

df_test = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3]], columns=['a','b','c']) 
cl = Foo(df_test)
cl.df.loc[0, 'a'] = 3 # change a default value in dataframe
print(cl.df)
print(cl.altered)
```

which prints the altered dataframe but cl.altered is still set to False.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I don't really know much about pandas. But the setter isn't called because the line was:

```
cl.df.loc[0, 'a'] = 3
```

It would have been called if the line was:

```
cl.df = 3
```

One thing you could do is to store a copy of the original `df` when the instance is initialized and do something like:

```
@property
def altered(self):
    return self._orig_df == self._current_df
```

Comment: Good suggestion, the only problem is that instances of the class will take up twice as much memory, this can be problematic as the dataframes can be quite large.